# How to grab matching hex string of fixed length data together with its label

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I wanted to grab data from a url. I wanted just to extract the hex string data starting with 0x format. Currently, I am still searching and trying to find something that will help.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://bscscan.com/readContract?m=normal&a=0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4"
address = url[44:]

searchstring = "0x"             # search for anything that starts with 0x

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")
pre = soup.select_one("readContractAccordion")

print ("Address: ", address)
print (pre)
```

Current Output:

```
Address:  0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4
None
```

Wanted Output:

```
Address:  0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4
  1. DOGE:                      0xba2ae424d960c26247dd6c32edc70b295c744c43
  4. _marketingWalletAddress:   0x12345411294d0fddf644800e3a524cb73ffdfe7f
  8. deadWallet:                0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead
 11. dividenTracker:            0x7cf7ea291e26bc3d8796c876f1d63befbdc5f22c
 23. owner:                     0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436
 28. uniswapV2Pair:             0xd6a499cbe432bfe88c62a27d7e1437ddafe3a95a
 29. uniswapV2Router:           0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://bscscan.com/readContract?m=normal&a=0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4"
address = url.split("a=")[-1]

searchstring = "0x"  # search for anything that starts with 0x
soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

print("Address", address)
for tag in soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and tag.text.startswith(searchstring)
):
    parent = (
        tag.find_parent("div", class_="collapse")
        .find_previous_sibling("div")
        .text
    )
    address = tag.text

    print("{:<35} {}".format(parent, address))
```

Prints:

```
Address 0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4
1. DOGE                             0xba2ae424d960c26247dd6c32edc70b295c744c43
4. _marketingWalletAddress          0x12345411294d0fddf644800e3a524cb73ffdfe7f
8. deadWallet                       0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead
11. dividendTracker                 0x7cf7ea291e26bc3d8796c876f1d63befbdc5f22c
23. owner                           0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436
28. uniswapV2Pair                   0xd6a499cbe432bfe88c62a27d7e1437ddafe3a95a
29. uniswapV2Router                 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitely works. What part I need to modify to return every field. I mean  everything from 1 - 30.

Comment: @rbutrnz I'd search for every tag with `class="card"` and get the contents of it.